# kill a linux process in php

Tags: php, linux

I am writing a php code for remote controlling some processes and devices that are connected to a linux pc. The codes are written in python. I can run the scripts and programs usnig php functions such as `exec()` or `system()` but I can not kill my processes.

I want to kill the python:

```
<?php 
$PID = exec("pidof python");
echo $PID;
$kill = "kill " . $PID;
exec($kill);
?>
```

It returns the correct PID number but does not kill the process.
I also tried `exec("kill #PIDnum");` but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the right permissions to do so?

Comment: The PHP server is not typically run as root, but as nobody, www, web, etc.

Comment: you need root privileges to do that. But i don't see a good reason to kill a process from PHP.

Comment: PHP with full root privs.  Nothing could go wrong there :-)

Comment: Thanks, I will check the privileges; but why killing a process from PHP is not a good reason? Does it make further problems?

Comment: The principle of minimum privilege suggests not to run the webserver as root as this may tend to enable bad people to do bad things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only kill processes from PHP that are owned by the userid running the web server on your system, which is usually set to a low-privilege account like "nobody", "www", web", etc.

It could work if the python were started from a PHP script.  But otherwise, no.

A work around is to append lines to a file from PHP, the file to contain a list of the PIDs to be killed.  This won't kill the processes, you will need to write a separate script to do that, in a language like bash or perl, python, etc. Have `cron` run that script as root, to periodically read the file, and kill the PIDs.  But then, it won't be instantaneous.  You could set up cron to run such a script every minute, though.

Comment: Excellent answer by Paul.  FYI: If you want the process to be killed instantaneously (instead of waiting for the next time that the cron job runs), then you can run the script that kills the process as a daemon instead of as a cron job.

Comment: Or in non-technical terms, don't use cron for the root script that actually does the killing, instead start that in /etc/rc.local, and make it a`while(1)` loop that loops forever, with a sleep for a few seconds after each run.